# When I edit my comment on a laravel post, it is the post that is edited

Tags: laravel

I am working on a post and comment system. I created comment and Post controllers and models. When a user is logged in and comments on a post, upon deleting or editing the comment, the post is edited. Same to if the logged in user is an admin.

//Comment Controller

```
public function edit(Comment $comment)
{
    if (auth()->user()->is_admin !== 1) {
        if ($comment->user_id !== Auth::id()) {
            abort(403);
        }
    }

    return view('comments.edit', ['comment' => $comment]);
}

public function destroy(Comment $comment)
{

    if (auth()->user()->is_admin !== 1) {
        if ($comment->user_id !== Auth::id()) {
            abort(403);
        }
    }
    //        dd($comment);
    $comment->delete();
    return redirect('posts/' . $comment->post->slug)->with('success', 'Comment deleted successfuly');
}

public function store(Request $request, `Comment $comment, $slug)
{
    $request->validate([
        'body' => 'required'
    ]);
    $post_id = Post::where('slug', $slug)->pluck('id');
    //        dd($post_id[0]);

    $comment->create([
        'user_id' => $request->user()->id,
        'post_id' => $post_id[0],
        'body' => $request->input('body'),
    ]);

    return redirect()->back();
}
// update
public function update( Comment $comment,Post $post)
{

    $comment->update([
        'body' => request()->body
    ]);

    return redirect('posts/' . $comment->post->slug)- 
    >with('success', 'Comment updated successfuly');
     }

   //form
   <x-panel >
<form action="{{route('comments.store', $post)}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="mt-6">
        <textarea name="body" cols="30" rows="" class="rounded w- 
 full text-sm  overflow-y-scroll" placeholder="Comment as {{auth()- 
 >user()->name}}" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="flex justify-end  border-gray-200 pt-3">
        <button type="submit" class="bg-gray-600 text-white 
 uppercase font-semibold text-md px-10 rounded-2xl hover:bg-gray- 
 800 hover:text-white">Post</button>
    </div>
  </form>
 </x-panel>
```

//Routes

```
Route::get('/posts',[PostController::class,'index'])->name('posts.index');
Route::get('/myposts',[PostController::class,'indexx'])->name('profileposts');
Route::get('/posts/{post:slug}', [PostController::class, 'show'])->name('posts.show');
Route::get('/posts/create/post', [PostController::class, 'create'])->name('posts.create'); //shows create post form
Route::post('/posts/create/post', [PostController::class, 'store'])->name('posts.store'); //saves the created post to the database
Route::get('/posts/{post:slug}/edit', [PostController::class, 'edit'])->name('posts.edit'); //shows edit post form
Route::put('/posts/{post:slug}/edit', [PostController::class, 'update'])->name('posts.update'); //commits edited post to the database
Route::delete('/posts/{post}/', [PostController::class, 'destroy'])->name('posts.destroy'); //deletes post from the database

Route::post('/posts/{post:slug}/comments', [CommentController::class, 'store'])->name('comments.store'); //store comment
Route::get('posts/comments/{comment:slug}/edit', [CommentController::class, 'edit'])->name('comments.edit'); //edit comment
Route::put('posts/comments/{comment:slug}/edit', [CommentController::class, 'update'])->name('comments.update'); //commits edited comment to the database
Route::delete('posts/comments/{comment:slug}', [CommentController::class, 'destroy'])->name('comments.destroy');
 });
```

1. What could be the issue?
2. Anyone to guide me on how to nest(add) replies.

That once I edit a comment, it is the comment that is edited, not a post.`

Comment: where is the code for saving the edited comment, ``update`` method for the comment?

Comment: No `update` method? What does your `<form>` look like?

Comment: Share your update() method code and blade file code of form.

Comment: I have edited the main post. All answers requested are therein.

Comment: @Nelson do you want to update the comment?

Answer (score 0):

Your for have mistake in route:

you should use this route:

```
<form action="{{route('comments.update', $post->id)}}" method="POST">
```

and also it´s recommended use add in form:

```
@csrf
@method('PUT')
```

all your form shold be:

```
<form action="{{route('comments.update', $post->id)}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
<div class="mt-6">
        <textarea name="body" cols="30" rows="" class="rounded w- 
 full text-sm  overflow-y-scroll" placeholder="Comment as {{auth()- 
 >user()->name}}" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="flex justify-end  border-gray-200 pt-3">
        <button type="submit" class="bg-gray-600 text-white 
 uppercase font-semibold text-md px-10 rounded-2xl hover:bg-gray- 
 800 hover:text-white">Post</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

and i´ll change this route:

```
Route::put('posts/comments/{comment:slug}/edit', [CommentController::class, 'update'])->name('comments.update'); //commits edited comment to the database
```

to:

```
Route::put('posts/comments/{comment:slug}/update', [CommentController::class, 'update'])->name('comments.update'); //commits edited comment to the database
```